# How can I solve this: $-e^{-5x}x^7(5x-8)=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm examining function slope and determine relative extrema of function (local minimum and local maximum)

The example is as following:
$
y = x^8 e^{-5x}
$

To do this I have to determine derivative of this function, which is:
$$
y' = 8x^7e^{-5x}+x^8(-5e^{-5x}) = -e^{-5x}x^7(5x-8)
$$

Then according to my notes I need to solve equation from derivative:
$
-e^{-5x}x^7(5x-8)=0
$

How to solve this equation?

Comment: Divide both sides by $e^{-5x}$. Then assume $x\neq 0$ and divide both sides by $x^7$.

Comment: Observe that $e^{-5x}\neq0$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Now it clarifies. $$e^{-5x}$$ was really confusing me what to do there.

Comment: Here's how you know to think about whether $e^{−5x}$ can be $0$: your whole expression $e^{−5x}x^7(5x−8)$ is a product, so it will equal $0$ if, and only if, at least one of its factors equals $0$. That means you can worry about each factor separately. You already know when $x^7(5x−8)=0$, so the only other possibility to consider is if $e^{−5x}=0$

Comment: If you think about exponentiation as repeated multiplication (with negative exponent corresponding to repeated division), then it should become clear that the only way for $e^{−5x}$ to be $0$ is if $x$ is infinite (so that you "keep dividing by $e$ forever"). Or if you know about logarithms, you can just take the log of both sides and see that $−5x=\log0$ which is "negative infinity".

Comment: As a point of interest, you really can say that $−e^{−5x}x^7(5x−8)$ "takes the value $0$ at (positive) infinity", or more accurately that it approaches the value of $0$ as a limit as $x$ increases. There are situations where this sort of thing can be very useful. But in general, you'd need to do more than check that the factor $e^{−5x}$ is $0$, since one of the other "infinite" factors might "cancel out" the $0$ when they were multiplied together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that $e^{-5x}$ will never be zero, so you can divided through by that.  Then it is easy to solve the equation, which is 
$$
x^7(5x-8)=0
$$
The two solutions are $x=0$ and $x=\frac85$.

Comment: Oh god. It is that simple. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 6):

Well, we have three cases

$$\begin{cases}0=-e^{-5x}\\0=x^7\\0=5x-8\end{cases}$$

Clearly, the first case is not possible.  For the second case, the solution is $x=0$.  For the last case, the solution is $x=\frac85$.

Answer (score 3):

When you have a product that equals zero, at least one of the factors has to equal zero.  $e^{-5x}$ is never zero, so you can divide by it.  You are left with $x^7(5x-8)=0$  Now take each factor and set it to zero, which you should be able to solve.  The solution is the union of these.